# Custom Post Type Template Insert not working properply

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I am trying to insert Custom Template file through the plugin that handle a custom post type. 
Rest of the plugin working great except the template including part.

```
class ClassName{

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'uniThemeRedirect') );
    }


    public function uniThemeRedirect(){

        global $wp_query;
        global $wp;

        // Specific Custom Post Type
        if( $wp->query_vars["post_type"] == "videos" ){
            $templateFilename = "single-videos.php";

            if( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templateFilename ) ){
                $return_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templateFilename;
            }
            else {
                $return_template = UNISLIDER_TEMPLATES . $templateFilename;
            }

            $this->doThemeRedirect( $return_template );
        } else {
            echo 'not working';
        }

    }


    public function doThemeRedirect( $template_url ){
        global $post, $wp_query;
        if( have_posts() ){
            echo $template_url;
            require_once ( $template_url );
        }
        else{
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }

    }

}

$handle = new ClassName();
```

I am following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template#answer-4975004 example.

But when i visit on the http://www.domain.com/videos where videos is my custom post type.

i get the 'not working' means no template include.
**Can anyone please help me what wrong i have done??**

**UPDATE: This is how i register the Custom Post Type**

```
$labels = array(
             'name'=>__('UniVideos', 'unislider'), 
             'singular_name'=>__( 'Videos', 'unislider' ), 
             'add_new'=>__( 'Add New', 'unislider' ), 
             'add_new_item'=>__( 'Add New Video' ), 
             'edit_item'=>__('Edit Video'), 
             'new_item'=>__('New Video'), 
             'view_item'=>__('View Videos Images'), 
             'search_item'=>__('Search Slide'), 
             'not_found'=>__('Noting Found'), 
             'not_found_in_trash'=>__('Nothing found in Trash'), 
             'parent_item_colon'=>''
         );

         $args = array(
             'labels'=>$labels, 
             'public'=>true, 
             'has_archive'=>true, 
             'publicly_queryable'=>true, 
             'show_ui'=>true, 
             'query_var'=>true, 
             'menu_icon'=>'', 
             'rewrite'=>true, 
             'capability_type'=>'post', 
             'hierarchical'=>false, 
             'menu_position'=>NULL, 
             'supports'=>array( 'title' )
         );

         register_post_type( 'videos', $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: I guess the problem of your code is the missing `die();` as last line of `doThemeRedirect` method.

---

After that, your code can be simplified a lot, using the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook instead of the `template_redirect` action hook.

Simplify means reduce the chances of bugs, or at least, let recognization of them simpler.

```
 public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'uniThemeRedirect') );
}


public function uniThemeRedirect( $template ){
    if(  get_query_var('post_type') == 'videos' || (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'videos') ) {

        // the 'single-videos.php' will be included for both
        // single and archive view of CPT 'videos'
        // to stop including for single view, remove
        // (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'videos') ) from if condition
        // to stop including for archive view, remove
        // get_query_var('post_type') == 'videos' from if condition

        $templateFilename = 'single-videos.php';
        $locate = locate_template( $templateFilename );
        if( $locate ) return $locate;
        if( file_exists( user_trailingslashit(UNISLIDER_TEMPLATES) . $templateFilename ) )
           return user_trailingslashit(UNISLIDER_TEMPLATES) . $templateFilename );
    }
    // die 'not working';
    return $template;

}
```

So you **don't** need the `doThemeRedirect` method at all.

This code is simpler than your, but more powerful (it supports child themes where the yours doesn't) and a bit more good-practised: there is no one global variable in it.

Comment: it's not working in this case, i tried to debug `$template` that returns the `post.php` page from the theme directory, and i want to include the `single-videos.php` from the plugin directory, it means `is_post_type_archive('videos')` return false.

Comment: for your information, i am trying to write plugin for a theme, the theme hand there custom template with the `post-{name}.php`, I don't think if its matter because all the custom templates has `Template Name: NameofTemplate`

Comment: i tried with your given code, but `if( is_post_type_archive('videos') ) {` always return false.

Comment: I have updated my question and added how i created custom post type.

Comment: I want to include `single-videos.php` on single page with the following URL: `http://www.domain.com/videos`. I tried with your updated code but still the same, not including the file :(

Comment: I got `Result not Found`, nothing goes into this condition `if(  get_query_var('post_type') == 'videos' || (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'videos') ) {`

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/videos` is **not** a single view, is an archive view. Or you have a page (I mean a page created in wp dasboard) with the slug 'videos'? @jogesh_p